# appear NetworkManagerHUD screen to right side

Tags: unity-game-engine, multiplayer

Hi all In my application when i added NetworkManagerHUD component a simple user interface is appearing at leftsde.could someone [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbJdQ.png)help me on this regard to appear this screen right side.

Answer (score 0):

Go inside NetworkManagerHUD script and change offsetX to whatever value you want.

```
void OnGUI()
{
            if (!showGUI)
                return;

            int xpos = 10 + offsetX;
            int ypos = 40 + offsetY;
//.......
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you check [NetworkManagerHUD](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkManagerHUD.html) inspector, it has exposed:

**offsetX** The horizontal pixel offset of the UI.

**offsetY** The vertical pixel offset of the UI..

Please use this.